# How to change sliding animation when opening new screens (using Codename One)?

Tags: java, codenameone

When I use `Display.getInstance().callSerially()` method, it will show a new screen by sliding from right to left.

I would like to know how to change the animation to sliding from "left-to-right" (so it feels like going back to the previous screen) and also from "bottom-to-top".

Answer (score 1):

Codename One has two methods to show a `Form`:

- `show()`
- `showBack()`

The only difference between them is the direction of the animation which is reversed for back.

If this isn't the use case you can use `CommonTransition` and play around with direction, speed, and type:

```
currentForm.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, false, 300));
currentForm.setTransitionInAnimator(null);
```

OR

```
currentForm.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, false, 300));
currentForm.setTransitionInAnimator(null);
```

Apply transition only to the currently showing form and not the nextForm.

Below, if called from within currently showing form will behave weirdly:

```
nextFormToShow.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, false, 300));
```

OR

```
nextFormToShow.setTransitionInAnimator(CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, false, 300));
```

Comment: I edited your answer with `showBack()` which I think is probably closer to what he is looking for